# Base Navigation Fragment for multiple Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

Is it possible to create a `Navigation Fragment` to contain my navigation back button click logic.

Multiple Fragment's that have a back button would then be able then inherit from the `Navigation Fragment`.

I'm new to Kotlin development. As you see below the `SigninFragment` inflates the view, I'm not sure how to get a reference to the view & back button in a parent `Navigation Fragment`

```
class SigninFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signin, container, false)

        // Navigation back button logic
        var headerBackButton = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.headerBackButton)
        headerBackButton.setOnClickListener {
            val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this@SignInFragment)
            navController.navigateUp()
        }

        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your problem right but could this be the trick?

```
open class NavigationFragment() : Fragment() {

    fun asignNavigationBackClickListener(backButton: View) {
        backButton.setOnClickListener {
            val navController = NavHostFragment.findNavController(this@NavigationFragment)
            navController.navigateUp()
        }
    }
}

class SigninFragment : NavigationFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_signin, container, false)
        asignNavigationBackClickListener(view.findViewById(R.id.headerBackButton))
        return view
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this code for going back to the previous activity:

```
headerBackButton.setOnClickListener {
    finish()
}
```